# Must write a java class constructor

Tags: java

I have been asked in a interview. It seems there is a scenario when, a constructor must need to write while writing a java class. I could not find a proper answer though. Please help me.

Cheers

Comment: *constructor must need to write* - What must the constructor write?! And why?

Comment: I don't get the question, can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you try and rephrase what you mean by "a constructor must need to write while writing a java class" please? :)

Comment: @Aniket which question you are referring too?

Comment: @Aniket I thought of writing your question is not clear

Comment: Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) Oracle document for concept and for example you can refer [this](http://kishangajjar.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/unit-2-prog-5-constructors-in-java/)

Answer (score 5):

You must write a constructor when your base class does not have a standard one, which takes no argument.

For example:

```
class A {

  public A(int value) {

  }
}

class B extends A {

}
```

This code does not compile. Java will try to add a default constructor to `B`, but it could not call `super()`, since `A` does not have a zero-argument constructor. Thus, you **must** define a constructor for `B`.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend a class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor you must define a constructor.